# Proper way of using SQL connection in c# for batch operations

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlconnection

Ok here my function for this purpose and i am not sure whether this is the perfect way or not

I think `srStored_Procedure_Name` is self explanatory

`List<string> lst_StoredProcedure_Variable_Names` provides stored procedure variable names

`List<List<object>> lst_Operation_Parameters` provides parameters that is going to be added each list has same number of objects as stored procedure variable name count

With below way i would use same connection to the server right no more than 1 connection will be opened during the whole insert operation

Ty very much for answers

**And 1 more question do i have to wrap this line in try catch block ? can there be any error that would cause application crash ?**

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection.srConnectionString))
```

*C# WPF .net 4.5 SQL server 2014*

```
public static bool batch_execute_SQL_stored_Procedure(string srStored_Procedure_Name, List<string> lst_StoredProcedure_Variable_Names,
    List<List<object>> lst_Operation_Parameters)
{
    bool blErrorHappened = false;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection.srConnectionString))
        {

        connection.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < lst_Operation_Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(srStored_Procedure_Name, connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = PublicSettings.irCommandTimeOutSettings_Second;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    for (int k = 0; k < lst_Operation_Parameters[i].Count; k++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(lst_StoredProcedure_Variable_Names[k], lst_Operation_Parameters[i][k]);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        blErrorHappened = true;
                        //log error here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        blErrorHappened = true;
        //log error here
    }
    return blErrorHappened;
}
```

Comment: The only real error you could get in the constructor call is if the connection string isn't valid.

Comment: @john ty for answer how much overhead do you think having try catch causes ? there wouldn't be never invalid string as it is static object and never changes during whole software

Comment: If the database were unavailable, or the timeout were exceeded, or a parameter could not be cast to the correct type, you'd get an exception back from the database. Without handling it, the exception will bubble up and potentially crash your application. There's little overhead in adding a try/catch block, it's a few lines of code extra that are unlikely to be executed in the program flow but could well prevent application crashes.

Comment: @barrick ty for comment it is better to be safe than sorry :D

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Keep the try/catch for the rest of it (the errors will likely come from the .Open() and .ExecuteNonQuery() calls, if any)